# Get line number of the last printed line on a PDF Page using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF in which I want to number each line that is printed and the get a following statistics

Also each page has to start numbering from zero

Total lines in pdf, total lines on each page, etc...

**ALL OF THESE ARE TO BE DONE `RUNTIME`. AND NOT AFTER CREATION OF `PDF`. THE PDF CREATED CANNOT BE OPENED AGAIN.**

So I dont have another shot at the PDF, how can I put line numbers in PDF specially when the text varies every time.

I have used page events but was not able to find any line events in the itext

I am Using `itext 2.1.5` with `JAVA`.

Comment: That's not supported. Also you're using an iText version that dates from March 8, 2009. That's mighty old...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is it supported in New version?

Comment: No. In the new version, you can use ColumnText to add content and ColumnText has a method named getLinesWritten(), but that doesn't add the actual numbers in front of the line that was written. That would require some extra development work on ColumnText.